# Resources for learning Stata

Tags: references, stata

I know of Cameron and Trivedi's Microeconometrics Using Stata.

What are other good texts for learning Stata?

Comment: I am tempted to say "R for Stata users", but I would get voted down for this :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The UCLA resource listed by Stephen Turner (below) is excellent if you just want to apply methods you're already familiar with using Stata.

If you're looking for textbooks which teach you statistics/econometrics while using Stata then these are solid recommendations (but it depends at what level you're looking at):

**Introductory Methods**
An Introduction to Modern Econometrics Using Stata by Chris Baum
Introduction to Econometrics by Chris Dougherty

**Advanced/Specialised Methods**
Multilevel and Longitudinal Modeling Using Stata by Rabe-Hesketh and Skrondal
Regression Models for Categorical Dependent Variables Using Stata by Long and Freese

Comment: In referring to other questions, don't say "above" or "below" as the order can change depending on votes or whether the answer is accepted, for example.

Comment: Baum's book is neither a real introduction to econometrics nor a real introduction to Stata. Somewhat disappointing ...

Answer (score 6):

UCLA has the best free resources you'll find anywhere.

https://stats.idre.ucla.edu/stata/

Answer (score 4):

I have done very well with reading the official documentation. It is well-written, sometimes injected with humour (!) and, if you're willing to spend the time to learn Stata properly, is an absolute goldmine.

Answer (score 3):

I have listed some resources on my [Stata page](http://f.briatte.org/teaching/quanti/stata.html). It includes links to the UCLA and Princeton tutorials, as well as a few more resources in several formats. The "[Stata Guide](http://f.briatte.org/teaching/quanti/stata.html#download)" document, which is very much a work in progress at that stage, is my personal contribution.

One of the fantastic things about Stata is the wealth of online and offline documentation, but never forget that the first resource to learn Stata is the very good set of documentation pages that you can access right away from Stata through the `help` command ([also available online](http://www.stata.com/help.cgi?help)).

If you prefer using books, Alan Acock's *A Gentle Introduction to Stata* combined with Lawrence Hamilton's *Statistics with Stata* will get you at a fairly high level of proficiency. You might then add a third book (like [Long and Freese](http://www.stata.com/bookstore/regmodcdvs.html)'s excellent handbook) focused on a special research interest.

Answer (score 2):

There are couple of good links with introductory material at Princeton Uni Library [website](http://libguides.princeton.edu/content.php?pid=27916&sid=459449).

Answer (score 2):

Alex Tabarrok posted a great list of resources here on [marginalrevolution.com](http://marginalrevolution.com/marginalrevolution/2011/01/stata-resources.html?utm_source=feedburner&utm_medium=feed&utm_campaign=Feed%3a+marginalrevolution/hCQh+%28Marginal+Revolution%29)

Gabriel Rossman shares a good introductory guide [here](http://gabrielr.bol.ucla.edu/stataprogramming.pdf).

Answer (score 2):

If you `search` on some keyword(s) in Stata, you will often be directed to articles in the *Stata Journal*. Many articles are written at an introductory or expository level and concern the language itself and how to program in Stata as well as how to use Stata for statistics, data management and graphics.

Alternatively, visit [the journal website directly](http://www.stata-journal.com) and search for material.

All articles in the *Stata Journal* are freely accessible online to all after 3 years from publication, so you can build up a personal collection of articles as .pdf relevant to your interests.

Full disclosure: I am an Editor of the *Stata Journal* and an occasional contributor.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend the Stata Press series. I'd especially recommend the Programming in Stata text as a primer to doing your own work.

Comment: http://www.stata.com/bookstore/books-on-stata/ is a natural starting point.